# Program to bubble sort a txt file in C

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, bubble-sort

I'm writing a C program to be given a txt file containing names of player and how many wins they have (its for a bigger game project), and sort them from highest to lowest amount of wins. While the code compiles and successfully orders the wins im experiencing a problem with the names where they seem to be stacking on top each other.

```
#include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>

    char name[20];
    int wins[20];


void main()
{

    FILE *fp;
    int i=0,size,j,swap;
    char ch; 

    fp=fopen("record.txt","r");
    if(fp==NULL)
    { 
    printf("\n Cannot open the file \n");
    exit(0);
    }
    while(ch!=EOF)
    {
    fscanf(fp,"%s %d",&name[i],&wins[i]);  
    ch=fgetc(fp); 
    i++;  
    } 
    size=i-1;
    for(i=1;i<size;++i)
    for(j=0;j<size-i;j++)
    if(wins[j+1]>wins[j])

    {

        swap    = wins[j];
        wins[j]   = wins[j+1];
        wins[j+1] = swap;

        swap      = name[j];
        name[j]   = name[j+1];
        name[j+1] = swap;
    }
    fp=fopen("sortedRecord.txt","w");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
    fprintf(fp,"%s %d \n",&name[i],wins[i]);
    printf ("%s %d \n", &name[i],wins[i]); 
    }


    fclose(fp); 

}
```

Here is the input file "record.txt"

```
Andrew 5
Billboy 10
Hill 7
Mill 1
```

And here is what i get when i run it.

```
BHAMill 10 
HAMill 7 
AMill 5 
Mill 1
```

I'm new to code so i know mine sucks but for the life of me i cant see exactly where its going wrong. Any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: You're trying to store strings in chars (`char name[20]` can only hold 20 characters, not 20 strings).  What you need is an array of char*.

Comment: You are trying to put strings into a char array. Each element of `char name[20];` can hold a char, whereas `fscanf(fp,"%s %d",&name[i],&wins[i]); ` with this, you are putting the entire string in it. You should have a 2d array or array of char pointers in order to do what you are doing. I am surprised that it doesn't crash.

Comment: @jwdonahue Or array of "array of characters" like `char name[20][1024]`

Comment: BTW, bubble sort, by definition, [sucks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Use). The best thing in your career as a programmer you can do with bubble sort is to unlearn it.

Comment: In addition, your use of scanf is inviting pretty terrible errors. I recommend you to read [this](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html). And always give your arrays bigger size than you can ever need, and always check the size when writing to them.

Comment: Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jwdonahue said the issue is with your definition of `name`. `char name[20]` creates an array of 20 `char`s, not 20 strings.

When you run the `while(ch!=EOF)` loop what's happening? First time through you find the address of the 0th element in `name` and write `Andrew` there so `name` has `['A', 'n', 'd', 'r', 'e', 'w', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0']` (the `\0` is the end of string character). Second time through you find the address of the 1st element in `name` and write `Billboy`, but the 0th element is still there and hasn't changed so you end up with the contents being `['A', 'B', 'i', 'l', 'l', 'b', 'o', 'y', '\0', '\0']`. Adding `Hill` to the 2nd position results in `['A', 'B', 'H', 'i', 'l', 'l', '\0', 'y', '\0', '\0']`. Then finally adding `Mill` gives the array `['A', 'B', 'H', 'M', 'i', 'l', 'l', '\0', '\0', '\0']`.

When you then go to sort scores you are sorting the characters in this array which end up as `['B', 'H', 'A', 'M', 'i', 'l', 'l', '\0', '\0', '\0']` (only the first four characters will be affected by your sort). In your print statement you then print the character array starting at the 0th, 1st, 2nd and 3rd positions respectively so you get `BHAMill`, `HAMill`, `AMill`, and `Mill`.

Hopefully that should help you enough to get you unstuck. :)

Comment: That dose make sense, you guys have been a huge help thanks!